# Good spam filter options for django blogs/comments

Tags: django, blogs, spam, spam-prevention

I am working on a simple django app that allows users to create posts and then comment on them. I would like to have some sort of spam filtering implemented. At the moment I am only doing honeypot checking and a captchta. But the problem is that users can still post spam (links/ads/etc), my main concern is links.

I have been looking at SpamBayes and am not sure how to apply it to my site at the moment.

Are there any simple lightweight solutions that will filter most spam from the posts?

I am thinking of creating a simple regexp filter that will scan each token and check to see if it matches urls/emails etc. The problem with this approach is that it might get ineffecient depending on how regexp's are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) via a [Django module](http://blog.akismet.com/2008/09/15/akismet-for-django/).  I use Akismet with my WordPress blog and it's over 99% effective at flagging spam.

Comment: James Bennett covers this in Practical Django Projects.  There's also Discus.

Comment: I heard about akismet before, I wanted a free solution though.

Comment: @Absolute0: The $5/mo fee for businesses may well be less than the cost of you maintaining your own filtering software.  Remember that creating your own solution will cost time, and time is valuable.  (If this is not for a business website, then Akismet *is* free.)